# Clip OSM basemap in Open Layers

Tags: openlayers

I'm using an OpenLayers-map on a website. I use an OSM base map. However, i don't want the entire world as a base map, instead I'd like to clip the extent of the OSM base map with another layer (in my case a national border).

Can i even do that?

Comment: Yes, have a look at maxExtents and resolutions, both of which can be passed as part of the options object that you pass to map constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've come up with a workaround. It's so very simple that I feel embarrassed that I didn't think of it earlier.

Instead of actually clipping the OSM base map I just created a shapefile that covers everything except the parts that I want to be displayed. After that I put it as an overlay on my map.

And here's the result

[image]